# How to determine when a file was created

Tags: shell

I have a .jar file that is compiled on a server and is later copied down to a local machine. Doing `ls -l`on the local machine just gives me the time it was copied down onto the local machine, which could be much later than when it was created on the server. Is there a way to find that time on the command line?

Comment: As jar files are just zip archives you can get the timestamp from the archive entries but that's about the best I think you can get. `unzip -l file.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` and `curl` have options that allow you to preserve the file's modified time stamp. This is close enough to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX-like systems do not record file creation time.

Each directory entry has 3 timestamps, all of which can be shown by running the `stat` command or by providing options to `ls -l`:

- Last modification time (`ls -l`)
- Last access time (`ls -lu`)
- Last status (inode) change time (`ls -lc`)

For example, if you create a file, wait a few minutes, then update it, read it, and do a `chmod` to change its permissions, there will be no record in the file system of the time you created it.

If you're careful about how you copy the file to the local machine (for example, using `scp -p` rather than just `scp`), you might be able to avoid updating the modification time. I presume that a `.jar` file probably won't be modified after it's first created, so the modification time might be good enough.

Or, as Etan Reisner suggests in a comment, there might be useful information in the `.jar` file itself (which is basically a zip file). I don't know enough about `.jar` files to comment further on that.

Comment: Indeed, I can't comment on what the timestamp in the jar file is going to represent but it will, at the very least, predate the file transfer time.